# WP CSS problems / Url Problems

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I've got some problemes with my WP.
I've got a distant web site and I need to modify it. So i copy it on a wamp server to work on local.
Problemes are coming ^^

First when i go into localhost/my_site/wp-admin and I log myself no css are loading, and workpress is new for me so it's a little bit difficult to doing that without css.

Second when i click on a link in my local web site I've got 2 time the url.

I mean : 127.0.0.1/my_site/127.0.0.1/my_site/mypageIneed.

And obviously that doesn't work.

EDIT

I fix the CSS problems

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If you already downloaded  database and all files from your cpanel and everything is settled up on your localhost including database import. Just search this plugin online and place it to your root directory  "Search-Replace-DB-master" run it on your browser and change all the links ( Ex. www.xyz.com/   to localhost/newsite/ ) . Good Luck !!